# render parts of template based on user role

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My question is about displaying only those parts of a template which a user is authorized for. 
Lets assume there is a project with just users and user roles and its generated templates and controllers by phx.gen.html. Setting up routes "/users" we get a nice table with all user data and buttons for "show", "edit" and "delete".

User roles may be just a normal "user" and an "admin". Now I want the admin to be able to delete and edit all users but the "user" should only be able to edit himself and what my question is about, he should only see those buttons for his entry.

I already set up some plugs for the respective actions, so the normal "user" can't edit, delete or even show other users but he shouldn't even be aware of the option to do so. So, I want to hide those buttons. Here are solutions I came across or up with, but they all seem to be not really applicable.

1. Using an "/admin" route and restrict the access to it. This seems to be the way which is used mostly but I don't want to do this since an admin is only a privileged normal user in my case and there is basically no need for a complete route for admins. I would have to create new controllers, new templates and so on.
2. So my next thought was: "Just render another template and delete those buttons from the users template". Well, it works but its basically the same as 1). I would have to duplicate content for all index.html's and for some other templates, too. Further, if I want to add another role, maybe a "manager" or something, I have to duplicate it again. This seems not to be maintainable over time.
3. Adding some logic to the template itself, like <%= if is_admin? do %> html-things <% end %>. I know it will not hurt at this point, since I double check permissions with my plugs in the controller but anyway... this also seems "dirty" since I don't want this logic in the template.

Anyone got another idea or maybe a reference to someone who discussed this? I was only able to find articles about 1) and how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to keep the permissions logic in one place and use it in the controller as well as template. Inspired by Ruby on Rails' old `cancan` gem, I define a function like:

```
defmodule MyApp.Can do
  def can?(_user, :create, Post), do: true
  def can?(user, :delete, %Post{} = post), do: user.is_admin || post.user_id == user.id
  ...
end
```

Now in the controller, use this function for authorization:

```
def delete(...) do
  ...
  if MyApp.Can.can?(current_user, :delete, post) do
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

And in the template:

```
<%= MyApp.Can.can?(@current_user, :delete, @post) %> <Delete Button> <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Dogbert. Thats not exactly what I looked for, but its a nice implementation of my point 3) with centralized logic. Looking deeper into it I found Policy_Wonk https://github.com/boydm/policy_wonk. I think I will use this. So, thanks again for leading me in the right direction ;-)

Comment: Just another addition: Policy_wonk was a little bit over the top for my case. What works for me now is using your solution @Dogbert but instead of calling MyApp.Can.can? in the controller actions, I call this in my Plugs. That way, the controller logic stays clean, authorization is handled by plugs and the pipeline will halt before any controller action is called, if somebody tries to do something he is not authorized for.